# How to repeat alarm from 8 AM to 10 PM android

Tags: android

I want to make an app in which notification come after every one hour from 8Am to 10Pm
how can i do 
here is code for repeat alarm after every one hour

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //After after 5 seconds
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60  , pi);
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled

Comment: here not mention the specific time that it repeat alarm between some time

Comment: so every day you want to play it ?

Comment: yes, I want to play every day from 8 AM to 10PM after every one hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to just set the alarm to fire once every hour and compare the time upon wake-up against your desired start and end times.

Another way would be to do the same, but discontinue the hourly alarms at 10pm and instead set one for 8AM. Then back to the hourly ones until 10pm again. Lather, rinse, repeat.

### EDIT:

You can do the time comparisons using something like this:

```
import android.text.format.Time;

...

private static final int START_HOUR = 10;
private static final int END_HOUR = 22;

...

Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();

int hour = now.hour;
if (hour >= START_HOUR && hour <= END_HOUR)
    // do something;
else
    // do something else;
```

Comment: can you give me code that how can i compare the time upon wake-up against desired start and end times.

Comment: I added sample code to the answer to do some time comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you could do by the two ways .

1: Set up alarm for every next hour and check for that action what you wanted to perform between time interval (in your case it will be 8 AM to 10 PM), so in other words alarm will play each hour but your action will perform in specific hour . This is less preferred way but that would works .

2.You can create one alarm manager which will call once in every day and and under that alarm manager you could start another alarm manager which start for that day only for specific hour.you should have to give different ID to `PendingIntent` in order to play multiple alarm